# How can We get friends list and circles of Google using API in PHP?

Tags: php, api, google-plus

I am trying to get friend's list and circles from google+ but not getting any specific API through which I can get those things. I am doing this all stuff in PHP.

If anyone have idea about this it would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) you can get access to a list of people that the user follows AND that they also permit you access to - but you have no guarantee that this is the full set of everyone in the person's circles. You are also not told which circle or circles these people are in.

Answer (score 3):

Check this
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list

List all of the people who this user has added to one or more circles. This list is limited to the circles that the user made visible to the requesting app. This method does not return circle information....

Answer (score 2):

this isn't possible. Star the issue here to register your support for the feature:
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=47

Answer (score 1):

Visit This https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/.. There Are just some scripts they provide which u can use in ur site.

Comment: Hi, I need exact friend's list and circles from user's profile. Above API seems does not provide such Result.

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ Domains API provides Google Apps customers with API access to create and manage circles on behalf of users within their Google Apps domain. This facilitates use cases such as